# Ajax returning data in new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a php function in my controller named form and I want to display some message according to the condition.

I am echoing the message inside the if else block. But instead of storing in msg parameter and displaying in the format as given in success function of AJAX it is displaying the message echoed in a new page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#sign_up").click(function() {

            var form_data = {
                firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
                secondName: $('#secondName').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('form/submit'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg == 'YES') {
                        $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>'); }
                    else if (msg == 'NO') {
                        $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>'); }
                    else {
                        $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>'); }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks to all who tried to help!!

Comment: `return false;` suggests this code is in a function ... a "submit" handler perhaps?

Comment: add a `alert(msg);` in success function and check what happens

Comment: Even if I remove return false; same error prevails

Comment: alert(msg)    is doing the same thing

Comment: It seems your ajax request is not running, Cant help without seeing complete code !, where is form_data is defined ?

Comment: What does `site_url('form/submit');` return ? because the url parameter expects a valid URI.

Comment: Edit your question with the controller code.

Comment: `site_url()` is a Wordpress function... not pure PHP

Comment: hardcode you url and it should work

Comment: Try to use e.preventDefault();, may be it prevent from running default function. That may help

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`  I think you are not seeing something... turn the error reporting on

Comment: Ya! the error is there itself ajax is not running

Comment: What to place instead of <?php echo site_url('form/submit'); ?>

Comment: @AmaanIqbal put e.preventDefault(); before defining form_data var, that is on starting on your function. And see if it works

Comment: After doing so my form is itself not being submitted

Comment: @AmaanIqbal have you also passed e i.e event in click event. ?

Comment: yes in the function parameter

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: No everything is running except ajax

Comment: Seems some type of error, because click event is triggered but ajax request is not sent instead of this it is submitting form i think, could you also post your form and button you are using u submit form. May be that helps

Comment: @AmaanIqbal no, i mean to html form not controller, your comtroller is working fine.

Comment: Try change your signup button type 'type="submit"' to 'type="button", it will prevent default submission of form, may help

Comment: And where is #secondName input is, i think that is #lastName

Comment: Then the form is not submitting at all

Comment: Actually the whole script is not working at all

Comment: Yeah, form will not be submitted instead of this it will send your ajax request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147502/discussion-between-raman-saluja-and-amaan-iqbal).

Comment: Posted a answer, check that, Hope it will help

Comment: Make sure you have your jquery library loaded BEFORE your jquery code. If you use say Firefox - Bring up the console using F12 and view the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sign_up_form").submit(function() {

        var form_data = {
            firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
            secondName: $('#lastName').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('form/submit'); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                if (msg == 'YES') {
                    $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>'); }
                else if (msg == 'NO') {
                    $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>'); }
                else {
                    $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>'); }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

here instead of using click event i recommend using submit event and there was error in `secondName: $('#secondName').val(),`, changed it to `secondName: $('#lastName').val(),`.
and your form will be

```
    <div id="alert-msg"></div>
 <?php 
      echo form_open("form/submit", array("id"=>"sign_up_form"));
  ?>
 <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName">
 </div>

 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">

 <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:20px">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sign_up">Sign Up</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use `preventDefault()` function like describe below. It will help you to stop redirecting your page to new page.

```
$("#sign_up").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault():
```

Second correction, In Ajax call add `dataType` like describe below.

```
$.ajax({ 
       url: '<?php echo site_url('form/submit'); ?>',
       type: 'POST', 
       data: form_data, 
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(msg) {
```

This will help you. Let me know if it not works.